# C# - How do I have 2 gameobjects ALWAYS have the same y values in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a cube in my scene that I have moved around. And I want another cube to always have the same y value. So if the first cube moved down 10 units I want the other to do the same.

My first cube was manually created in the editor, but my other one is placed using scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could as already said use a parent child relation, but then every movement of the parent will cause movement on the child for x, y and z coordinates.

If you want the other object follow **only** the y coordinate and not the others, then you cannot use a parent-child relationship for that.

Instead, you could use a script (inspiration from : https://answers.unity.com/questions/543461/object-follow-another-object-on-the-x-axis.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class SameYCoordinateAsOther : MonoBehaviour {

     Transform otherTransform;

     void Start() {
        // you can set a reference to the "parent" cube
        otherTransform = GameObject.Find("cube1").transform;
     }

     void Update() {
        // here we force the position of the current object to have the same y as the parent
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, otherTransform.position.y, transform.position.z);
     }
}
```

And you just attach this script to any object that must 'follow' the first cube on the y-axis.

This script will force the second object to have the same y-value of the first.

If you do **not** want them to have the same values, but only that the amount of of movement is the same, this will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: That works perfectly, but I was thinking about one suggestion: ideally, if you make your "parent" move via script, you don't want to get that re-location in "child" Update(). To optimize you can suscribe that line of code to a callback in your parent.